# Does mongodb atlas realm support serverside functions using pipeline in free tier?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

Prototyping using mongodb atlas/realm free tier. "collection.find()" functions test ok from within mongo cloud ui. When I write a pipeline query e.g. $match, I get message " cannot use $match in free tier". Is this for real? i.e. free tier has blocked all pipeline functionality, or have I somehow triggered this error with incorrect code. Have googled for hours but cannot find this info.

Comment: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/free-shared-limitations/

Answer (score 0):

I must have had a code error that raised this message. Following function returns data in Realm:

```
exports = function(arg){
 
  let collection = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas").db("gif-battle").collection("players");
  
  const pipeline = [
    { "$match": {
      "plyr_typ": "c",
    } } ,
    
    
    {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "plyr_nm": 1,
      "testAddField": "HelpMeRhonda",
    }
    }
 
  ]
  return collection.aggregate(pipeline).toArray()
  .then(players => {
    console.log('d1:', players[0].plyr_nm);
    
    return players
  })
   
};
```

also curious ... mongodb Jumpstart tutorial recommends replacing mongodb-stitch-browser-sdk from npm with mongodb-realm-browser-sdk. Have looked all over for this. Does it exist?